# Image labeling and finding centroids in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

My problem is that I have a radar image in `png` format. (Sorry, but i had to remove the image as my colleague says it a copyright infringement of the German Weather Service)

I want to read the image in MATLAB. Then read all the clouds, and label each cloud with a unique index. This means that each pixel belonging to a certain cloud is labeled with the same index `i`. Calculate the center of `area(coa)` of each cloud and then I should be able to measure distances between clouds from one coa to another.

Some similar work I know was done in IDL. I tried using that but it would be much easier for me if I'm able to do all this in MATLAB and concentrate more on the result, rather then spend time learning IDL.

So, before jumping in, I want to know if all this is possible in MATLAB. If yes, can you guide me a little on how I can extract the cloud and label them?

Comment: where is the cloud in that image?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK -  All that u see in the image are clouds only.

Comment: Oh,sorry. I have a quite different picture of cloud in my mind :). Anyway try this link : http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/06/02/cell-segmentation/

Comment: this link also :http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/examples/correcting-nonuniform-illumination.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First do some basic image analysis such as thresholding or median filtering and so forth, to reduce noise if relevant. 
Then you can use [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) to  label each cloud with a unique index. The use [`reigonprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html)  to find the centroids.

Here's a very basic code sample:

```
d=imread('u09q8.png');
bw = im2bw(d,0.1); % thereshold at 50%
bw = bwareaopen(bw, 10); % Remove objects smaller than 10 pixels from binary image
bw=bwlabel(bw); % label each cloud 
stats=regionprops(bw,'Centroid'); % find centroid coordinates of all labeled clouds
```

Comment: Yes, i would like to do some cleaning up by shareholding. And i think regionprops can be a lot helpful further on too, considering so much it can do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wow thanks..Can you also tell me how can i see the resultant image with the threshold and if possible labels marked on each cloud.

Comment: you can use `imagesc(bw)`. this will color encode each label to a different color given the colormap (default is `jet`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
Regarding the cloud detection, it is a step by step process.
It will be based on the algorithm you are going to use. You can start [here.](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/object-recognition.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. This can be done using [k-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).
You can read about [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) and [`kmeans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html). The example given in the official documentation of `kmeans` shows exactly what you need.

For example, if you want to cluster your image into 5 clouds:

```
%// Read the image
I = imread('clouds.png');
[y, x] = find(I);             %// Obtain all coordinates
y = size(I, 1) - y + 1;       %// Adjust y-coordinates
K = 5;
[idx, c] = kmeans([x, y], K); %// Classify clouds into K clusters
```

Now `idx` stores the corresponding cluster indices and `c` stores the coordinates of the centroids.

To draw the results, you can do something like this:

```
%// Plot results
figure, hold on
scatter(x, y, 5, idx)         %// Plot the clusters
plot(c(:, 1), c(:, 2), 'r+')  %// Plot centroids
text(c(:, 1) + 10, c(:, 2), num2str((1:K)'), 'color', 'r')  %// Plot cluster IDs
```

Note that this method requires predetermining the number of clusters `K` in advance. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13916-simple-tool-for-estimating-the-number-of-clusters) to attempt to automatically detect the number of clusters.

*EDIT: Due to the copyright claim I removed the resulting image.*

Comment: @Vikram I've added an example for your convenience.

Comment: Thank you Eitan. But in this way it just divides the cloud filed into clusters(group of clouds), while what i want is to separate out each and every individual cloud (not in contact with any other cloud).

Comment: @Vikram In that case use Natan's solution, which detects independent regions of pixels and automatically classifies them as clouds. You can still use the last part of my solution to plot the results.